# Exception during start.dfs.sh

Tags: java, hadoop

I set up a two node cluster using hadoop.

When I run `start-dfs.sh` I got this error:

```
starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-mohit-ubuntu.out
slave: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-balaji-ubuntu.out
slave: Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/PlatformName
slave: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName
slave: at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
slave: at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
slave: at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
slave: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
slave: at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
slave: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
slave: Could not find the main class: org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName. Program will exit.
slave: Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/datanode/DataNode
master: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-mohit-ubuntu.out
master: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-hadoop-secondarynamenode-mohit-ubuntu.out
```

After getting this error I changed the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` to `export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${HADOOP_CLASSPATH}:$HADOOP_HOME/lib/commons*.jar:$HADOOP_HOME:$HADDOP_HOME/hadoop-core-0.20.203.0.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/conf`

But it didn't help.

Comment: See the following stack overflow question. I answered it there 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183164/hadoop-error-can-not-start-all-sh/14932469#14932469

Answer (score 0):

It kind of seems like the jar files do not exist on the slave node. Could the installation or configuration of the slave be incorrect.

Comment: David: All java files are there on slave node

Answer (score 0):

or you can look up my blog where I have explained it. Also post your config files so we can debug them. http://blog.abhinavmathur.net/2013/01/adding-more-nodes-to-hadoop-cluster.html